# Returning value by a thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, return

Having this :

```
public Item_DataColl invoke_command_READ(string UCPTName)
{
    networkingThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(thread_command_READ));
    networkingThread.Start(new readingThreadParameter(UCPTName));
}
private Item_DataColl thread_command_READ_result(object parameter)
{
    readingThreadParameter p = parameter as readingThreadParameter;
    Item item;

    if (p.UCPT_Name != null)
    {
        Item_DataColl resultSet;
        try
        {
            OnProgressBarUpdate(progressBar.UnknownEnd);
            resultSet = connector.command_READ(p.UCPT_Name);
            readOperationDone(resultSet);
            OnConsoleWriting(string.Format("[READING] Lecture réussie : {0} = {1}", ((Dp_Data)resultSet.Item[0]).UCPTname, ((Dp_Data)resultSet.Item[0]).UCPTvalue[0].Value), ILonConnectorConsoleResultType.RESULT);
            return resultSet; // HERE, I WANT TO RETURN RESULT
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            OnConsoleWriting(e.ToString(), ILonConnectorConsoleResultType.ERROR);
        }
        finally
        {
            OnProgressBarUpdate(progressBar.Invisible);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to execute a SOAP request and to send the result. To make the application "non-blocking", i've used Thread.

The soap request works perfectly, but i have trouble to send a result just after the end of the thread. I will have to keep track of it and when the thread is over, to send back the result to another class.

How can i perform this ?

Comment: Have you considered using tasks instead - as they easily return values at the end

Comment: use `Task`s or `async/await` or a callback method, this depends on your architecture, which you didn't show us

Comment: Yes, i think Task may be a good solution, can you show me by an example how i need to perform this please ?

Answer (score -1):

Well.. this solution CAN BE WRITTEN WAY BETTER.. but I'm currently working with the code you already posted.

The approach - using a callback (with a delegate):

First - declare a delegate in your class scope

```
private Action<Item_DataColl> OnResultSetComplete;
```

Second - assign the delegate with some function BEFORE calling your thread

```
public Item_DataColl invoke_command_READ(string UCPTName)
    {
        OnResultSetComplete = (resukts) =>
        {
             // DO SOMETHING HERE
        };
        networkingThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(thread_command_READ));
        networkingThread.Start(new readingThreadParameter(UCPTName));
    }
```

Finally - change your read result function:

```
private Item_DataColl thread_command_READ_result(object parameter)
    {
        readingThreadParameter p = parameter as readingThreadParameter;
        Item item;

        if (p.UCPT_Name != null)
        {
            Item_DataColl resultSet;
            try
            {
                OnProgressBarUpdate(progressBar.UnknownEnd);
                resultSet = connector.command_READ(p.UCPT_Name);
                readOperationDone(resultSet);
                OnConsoleWriting(string.Format("[READING] Lecture réussie : {0} = {1}", ((Dp_Data)resultSet.Item[0]).UCPTname, ((Dp_Data)resultSet.Item[0]).UCPTvalue[0].Value), ILonConnectorConsoleResultType.RESULT);
                if (OnResultSetComplete != null) OnResultSetComplete(resultSet); 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                OnConsoleWriting(e.ToString(), ILonConnectorConsoleResultType.ERROR);
            }
            finally
            {
                OnProgressBarUpdate(progressBar.Invisible);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why didn't you use the `await` or tasks?

Comment: the question was about **threads**.- the old fashion way.. when somebody asks a question I first - answer the original question and only then - try to suggest improvements... but since i was down-voted I don't really think to bother myself on this one